# Why is snmp v1 queries faster than snmp v2c?

Tags: snmp

I have noticed that when I execute a plugin using snmp v1, the response is fast.

Example:

```
time /usr/lib/centreon/plugins/centreon_windows_snmp.pl --plugin=os::windows::snmp::plugin --mode=memory --hostname=x.x.x.x --snmp-version='1' --snmp-community=xxx
OK: RAM
real    0m0.589s
user    0m0.080s
sys     0m0.025s
```

Now with version 2c:

```
time /usr/lib/centreon/plugins/centreon_windows_snmp.pl --plugin=os::windows::snmp::plugin --mode=memory --hostname=x.x.x.x --snmp-version='1' --snmp-community=xxx
UNKNOWN: SNMP GET Request : Timeout
real    0m9.538s
user    0m0.127s
sys     0m0.056s
```

Can anyone tell me why there is such difference?

Comment: Please review your question. The second one is still in v1. Generally speaking v1 and v2c does not have much differences but the actual SNMP agent you talk to might have its own logic. You have to consult the agent vendor/developers for more details.

Comment: You seem to be comparing a "good" access vs. a "bad" access, in that the community seems to be bad. If the community is bad, then the request will timeout.

Answer (score 1):

The second request took longer because it didn't work. The delay you witnessed was your computer waiting for a timeout period to pass. It has nothing to do with how long the data took to be returned, because it *wasn't* returned.

You might need to consult your sysadmin or vendor to find out why your query didn't work, if the hostname and community string were the same in both cases. Otherwise double check your hostname and community string for the failing case.

Note that the SNMP version used is v1 in both cases so the version has nothing to do with it either (unless you've mis-doctored the quote, rather than copy-pasting it).

Comment: Good answer.  Also, worth noting is that some devices only implement SNMP version 1, which makes any SNMPv2c or v3 query look like a "request timeout" from the client's perspective.  Generally, it's better to test SNMP reachability using the net-snmp commandline tools, to rule out bugs in collector programs.